# PCA computation on 2D vectors of type double

Tags: c++, opencv, pca

I am trying to run PCA on a dataset which I have stored into a 2D vector from a file as follows:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > tmpVec;
while(std::getline(file, numStream))
{
    std::istringstream buffer(numStream);
    std::vector<double> line((std::istream_iterator<double>(buffer)),
                         std::istream_iterator<double>());
    tmpVec.push_back(line);
    i++;
}
```

Now I need to run PCA on this for which according to my understanding I need to convert this to type cv::Mat. This is being done as follows:

```
cv::Mat dst(row, col, CV_64F, &tmpVec);
```

And thrn i run PCA on it as:

```
cv::PCA pca(dst, cv::Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, 2);
```

When I try printing it out on screen after PCA computation i end up with garbage values.
I just need to figure out how to run PCA on a 2D double vector.
Any help with this or pointing me in the right direction would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "(std::istream_iterator<double>(buffer)), std::istream_iterator<double>()" looks inconsistent. Have you printed the values in the vector as well as the matrix?

Comment: Yeah the code there is working just fine. Makes the correct output. It is the pca computation and the convertion to cv::Mat that is causing an issue.

Comment: just saying, the address of a std::vector is not the address of the 1st element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this:

```
cv::PCA pca(dst, cv::Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, 2);
```

expects a cv::Mat with **continuous** data as input, which is not satisfied by a `std::vector<std::vector<double> > tmpVec;`

try like:

```
cv::Mat tmp;
while(std::getline(file, numStream))
{
    ...
    cv::Mat m = cv::Mat(line).t();  // we need a row-vec
    tmp.push_back(m);
}
cv::PCA pca(tmp, cv::Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, 2);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the ans. I still have a small doubt. Running PCA is supposed to reduce my feature set if I am not mistaken. In this case would how do i get back the reduced feature set data?

Comment: you have to use pca.project(features) to get the reduced features

Comment: so basically something like pca.project(3)? the number of features that i want? And thanks so much for your help..

Comment: cmon, [rtfm](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#pca-project) ;) input should be a single row Mat